# Java application (JSF, Jboss Seam, JBOSS AS 6, Hibernate, JTDS) with large data flow in a SQL Server database, begins to do transaction lock

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jsf, jboss-seam

We now have an application that serves several clients, but it happens that we get a big client with an average of 1000 simultaneous accesses, and now our application, ends up in lock, for a great time, this happens only with a large data flow in the bank, approximately 5,000 operations per second, this could somehow be some limitation of JBoss Seam (at times it is triggered @Syncronized exception), until in the database begins to be stored several different locks in the database, and the application to Operate with few users (~ 300 users).

I have tried everything a little, if you can help me, I thank you very much.

EDIT:

Hi, with some tests done, I see that my problem is a bottleneck of great information in the database, have already had some problem of this type using hibernate + SQL SERVER

Comment: For questions like this, it is advised to hire a consultant. Stackoverflow is not the right place for them.

Comment: Any hypothesis or similar problem would be valid for me.

Comment: You have tried **everything** (albeit a 'little') and expect a (any) hypothesis. You then stand great chance that you already tried that. 'Deadlock', thread (un-)safety, Bug in Seam, Bug in your code, Bug in database... Is this all helpful? I doubt it. It is way too generic for that (my 'suggestions' as well as your question. And getting into details is impossible unless you have a small piece of code that you can identify as the culprit. Sorry, it is not personal that we don't want to help, it just is beyond the scope of stackoverflow (to broad)

Comment: Tudo bem eu entendi, vou buscar ser mais categórico. até o momento obrigado

Comment: One other thing in the general Stackoverflow 'site' is to use English. Remarkably, (2 visits to Brazil, Spain and speaking a little French, good German and Dutch, I do understand what you said. Boa sorte

Comment: Oh, sorry. thks

Comment: Hi, with some tests done, I see that my problem is a bottleneck of great information in the database, have already had some problem of this type using hibernate + SQL SERVER